# i wanna work to make an object to property value of an array

Tags: php, arrays

```
[
   {
       name: "file_id",
      content: "7"
   },{
      name: "file_hash",
      content: "blahblahblah"
   },
]
```

array A

```
[
   "file_id" : "7",
   "file_hash" : "blahblahblah"
]
```

array B

I wanna change A to B
Is there any method that makes like that out of PHP method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function for that but you can do it using loop.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($a as $item) {
     $result[$item->name] = $item->content;
}
```

But keep in mind that if you've got non-unique names, your values will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array = array();

foreach($array_with_objects as $object) {
   $array[$object->name] = $object->content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(); 

foreach($arr_with_obj as $obj) {
   $arr[$obj->name] = $obj->content;
}
```

Genetared array will be associative with index & values what you want ......

-
Thanks